# Div containing other divs does not have proper height

Tags: css, html, height

I have a 'frame' containing two divs which are respectively aligned on the left and on the right. Unfortunately, the main `div` does not have the proper height to englobe the inner divs.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="frm">
   <div id="a">aaa<br>aaa</div>
   <div id="b">bbb</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#frm {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#a {
    background: blue;
    float: left;    
}

#b {
    background: green;
    float: right;
}
```

Here is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mPH4H/

I should see a red frame, but there is none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The floated elements are removed from the flow of the document, so the parent container thinks that it has nothing inside of it. You can add `overflow:auto` to your CSS rules for `#frm` to bring the background back and "contain" the floated children:

```
#frm {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mPH4H/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:hidden;` will give height to `#frm`

Try:

```
#frm {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mPH4H/4/)

OR

Clear floats:

HTML:

```
<div id="frm">
    <div id="a">aaa<br>aaa</div>
    <div id="b">bbb</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mPH4H/5/)

Answer (score 1):

i think this is worked as fine:

```
#frm {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#a {
    background: blue;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;    
}

#b {
    background: green;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```